# What Langchain functions should I use to create a program that takes a balance sheet as input text and gives out different ratios?

Tags: finance, openai-api, langchain

I want to use the langchain functions and use the chat GPT API to perform an app that does this. How do I use the API to extract the different values for such and such years (there could be info from multiple years) so that I can calculate this? also have to do a swot analysis.

I tried manually doing it but I figured I also need to factor that data formats might not always be the same.
I wasn't really able to figure out exactly which functions to use within Langchain.